# Can someone help me figure out why my code isn't working properly?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int fight();
int lowblow();
int eyes();

int run();
int underground();
int officebuilding();
int main()
{
    int choice1;
    int fchoice2, fchoice3;
    int rchoice2, rchoice3;
    cout << "As you’re walking down the street you feel somebody grab your shoulder, when you turn around to see. You notice the person is holding a knife towards you and demanding for your valuables." << endl; 
    cout << "Do you fight or run?" << endl;
    cout << "1 - Fight" << endl;
    cout << "2 - Run" << endl;
    cin >> choice1;
    while (choice1 != 1 && choice1 != 2) {
        cout << "Do you fight or run? " << endl;
        cout << "1 - Fight" << endl;
        cout << "2 - Run" << endl;
        cin >> choice1;
    }

    if (choice1 == 1) {
        fchoice2 = fight();
        while (fchoice2 != 1 && fchoice2 != 2) {
            fchoice2 = fight();
        }
        if (fchoice2 == 1) {
            fchoice3 = lowblow();
            while (fchoice3 != 1 && fchoice3 != 2) {
                fchoice3 = lowblow();
            }
        }
        if (fchoice2 == 2) {
            fchoice3 = eyes();
            while (fchoice3 != 1 && fchoice3 != 2) {
                fchoice3 = eyes();
            }

            if (choice1 == 2) {
                rchoice2 = run();
                while (rchoice2 != 1 && rchoice2 != 2) {
                    rchoice2 = run();
                }
                if (rchoice2 == 1) {
                    rchoice3 = underground();
                    while (rchoice3 != 1 && rchoice3 != 2) {
                        rchoice3 = underground();
                    }
                    if (rchoice3 == 1) {
                        officebuilding();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int fight()
{
    system("clear");
    int c2;
    cout << "You choose to fight off the attacker and suddenly all those self-defense classes come rushing into your mind.As you fight to defend yourself, you find yourself getting outmatched and have to try something drastic to survive." << endl; 
    cout << "1 - Go for the low blow" << endl;
    cout << "2 - Go for the eyes " << endl;
    cin >> c2;
    return c2;
}
int lowblow()
{
    system("clear");

    cout << "You catch your attacker off guard and land the hit, to your surprise the attack proves ineffective.In retaliation you get hit so hard that you start seeing stars and soon blackout leaves you defenseless.Now you are knocked out and getting your valuables taken." < endl;   
                                                                             
    cout << "The End" << endl;
    return 0;
}

int eyes()
{
    system("clear");

    cout << "Using the element of surprise to try fighting back gave you no advantage, so you resort to another tactic. You’ve seen it in movies and it always worked out there. You decide to go for the eyes and to your surprise it works. You use this opportunity to escape and get to safety, all while keeping your valuables safe. "<< endl;
    cout << "The End" << endl;
    return 0;
}
int run()

{
    system("clear");
    int c2;
    cout << " While running down the street to loose the attacker, you noticed that there was an underground subway a little down the road.Immediately to your left there is an office building you could run into and try to lose your attacker there."<< endl; 
    cout << "1 - Underground ?" << endl;
    cout << "2- office building?" << endl;
    cin >> c2;
    return c2;
}

int underground()
{
    system("clear");

    cout << "As you make your way towards the underground subway station you notice rushing out.In a desperate attempt to reach safety,        you run down the stairs while narrowly avoiding others.Upon arriving at the station you look back and notice that you lost your attacker.You are safe now.";            
    cout << "The End" << endl;
    return 0;
}
int officebuilding()
{
    system("clear");
    cout << "A spontaneous decision leads you into an office building, while it may look safe, upon entering you notice everything is silent as the building seems to be completely empty.None of it matters however, since you have to escape at any cost in order.While trying to find a good way to lose the attacker you hear footsteps behind you.The attacker has cornered you and has taken your valuables." << endl; 
    cout << "The End" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I am suppose to be writing a branching-path story. I am not sure why after I pick a choice it starts flashing and for the other choice it isn't even working. I'm not exactly sure where to fix these errors in the code. I'm not sure if I messed up somewhere in the functions or while loop. I've tried changing some things around but nothing seems to work.

Comment: OT: please learn "how to indent" your code, it will help both you and the people that have to read it

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: I fixed the code format. You probably needed to consult this: [https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) specifically look at the example for `console.log("Hello, World");`

Comment: This can not be the real code you are running, as C++ does not allow literal newlines in strings.

Comment: Suggestion: Write less code before testing. Ideally write a few lines, just enough to accomplish one easily testable thing, test it, and move on to adding a few more lines only after you've proved that the last few lines behave exactly as required. If you have a mistake, usually it's easy to find because it's in those few added lines. If you write 100 lines of code, you have a much larger surface area to search AND you probably have multiple mistakes.

Comment: As you get better at programming you'll be able to write larger pieces of code at a time, but even the masters rarely write more than one function at a time unless the functions are so trivial that they are fool-proof.

Comment: Side node: You have many `while` loops with a function call immediately before the `while` loop, and then the same function call inside the `while` loop. That is a lot of unnecessary code duplication. If you change the `while` loops to `do`...`while` loops, then you no longer need to make these function calls immediately before the loop. For example, `fchoice2 = fight(); while (fchoice2 != 1 && fchoice2 != 2) { fchoice2 = fight();}` can be changed to `do { fchoice2 = fight();} while (fchoice2 != 1 && fchoice2 != 2);`.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `underground()` in a while-loop waiting for `rchoice3` to be 1 or 2, but `underground()` always returns 0, so `rchoice3` is always 0..

```
while (rchoice3 != 1 && rchoice3 != 2) {
   rchoice3 = underground();
}
```

I think you need to change this block:

```
                if (rchoice2 == 1) {
                    rchoice3 = underground();
                    while (rchoice3 != 1 && rchoice3 != 2) {
                        rchoice3 = underground();
                    }
                    if (rchoice3 == 1) {
                        officebuilding();
                    }
                }
```

To:

```
                if (rchoice2 == 1) {
                    underground();
                } else {
                    officebuilding();
                }
```

Comment: But `underground()` always return 0. The user does not have any option there.

Comment: Yes, you're right about that, I'll edit my response to be more clear for future reference :)

Comment: @VincentBitter: If you to reply to one person specifically and want them to get notified of your reply, then you must write `@` and the name of that person. Otherwise, they may not notice your reply. Press the "Help" button when writing a comment for further information. However, you will be notified automatically of all comments to your answer, so it is not necessary for other people to use `@` to notify you.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Thanks, will do that in the future!

Comment: ...or hope that they will come back by chance ;). We can delete obsolte comments